# R text mining filtering string from text

Tags: r, text-mining

I was wondering if there's an existing R function that given a text and a list of strings as input, will filter out the matching strings in the list that are found within the text?

For example,

```
x <- "This is a new way of doing things."
mywords <- c("This is", "new", "not", "maybe", "things.")
filtered_words <- Rfunc(x, mywords)
```

Then filtered_words will contain "This is", "new" and "things.".

Is there any such function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)`.  The output will be a `list`, which can be `unlist`ed to convert it to a `vector`.

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(x, mywords))
#[1] "This is" "new"     "things."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filterWords = function(x, mywords){
  splitwords = unlist(strsplit(x, split = " "))
  return(splitwords[splitwords%in%mywords])
}
```

This is one way of approach. However this will not find the the words with two sub words like "this is". But I thought it might give you little more information on what you asked.